# Clonezilla restoring to a different partition

Tags: system-recovery, clonezilla

After a crash on my hard drive, I had to start from scratch. I reorganized the different systems and their appropriate partitions.

I had the required partitions and their sizes set up. 
The only difference being that they were numbered differently:
my original partitions `sda12` and `sda13` were now `sda6` and `sda7`.

Problem is, the saved Clonezilla images can only be restored to the original `sda12` and `sda13`.

Is there some way to restore the images to the new setup on `sda6` and `sda7`?

Answer (score 2):

As you have noted, this cannot be achieved automatically through the usual Clonezilla interface.  However, it can be
accomplished with manual intervention by following a couple of simple steps documented
on the [Clonezilla FAQ page](https://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/102_restore_image_to_different_partition.faq#102_restore_image_to_different_partition.faq).

For example, how can I restore an image of a partition to different partition,
e.g. restore the image of /dev/sda5 to /dev/sda6?  By following the following steps.

### Steps to follow

Create the new target partition /dev/sda6, making sure that its size
is equal to or larger than the original /dev/sda5 partition for which you
have a restorable Clonezilla image.

Now, make a copy of the Clonezilla image directory of the original
partition.  Here we will use the image "my-image" as an example, e.g.

```
cp -a /home/partimag/my-image /home/partimage/my-image-new
```

Now we have to change some files in this new image directory: /home/partimage/my-image-new.

Rename all the file names with the partition location identifier in them
from that of the original partition to the identifier of the new target
partition (eg.: /home/partimag/my-image-new/sda5* as
/home/partimag/my-image-new/sda6*). Eg.:

```
mv /home/partimag/my-image-new/sda5.ext4-ptcl-img.gz.aa /home/partimag/my-image-new/sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.gz.aa

mv /home/partimag/my-image-new/sda5.ext4-ptcl-img.gz.ab /home/partimag/my-image-new/sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.gz.ab
```

Next, modify the contents of /home/partimage/my-image-new/parts text file in the
same folder, again replacing the identifier of the original partition
with the identifier of the new target partition (eg.: replace "sda5" with "sda6").

Having made these changes to adapt the image to a new target
partition, you can now attempt to restore to the new and different
partition location.  Select the latter, adapted (my-image-new) image from the
Clonezilla repository and the new target partition location using the usual Clonezilla interface and it should now
allow you to restore it to the new partition location (/dev/sda6).

### Advanced (expert) parameters, if the two partitions differ in size

There are also some advanced (expert) parameters, again documented on the [Clonezilla site](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image/advanced/09-advanced-param.php), that can help with this if the two partitions differ in size.

In particular, the  "-r" option to resizes the file system in the new partition automatically.

Note that to restore an individual partition, you probably do NOT want
to use the "-k1" option which adjusts the partition table, as it adjusts the **WHOLE** partition table.

Comment: This worked for me for Windows 10 disk and Clonezilla v3 thanks. Before this, I was fiddling with external SATA to USB adapters. I must admit restoring parts onto a disk of applicable size, just to then savedisk its image so I could restore onto the absolute destination, was cumbersome to say the least. Kudos for explanation and pointing to the relevant docs.